# Active Directory microsoft exchange groups

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server

If I add a user to more than one Active directory groups, and send an email to all of these groups, will the user get multiple emails (one per group) or just one email? Is Exchange clever enough to determine that it is the same user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange will only send the message one time, as long as the groups you're sending to are in the same organization.  This may be an issue in very old versions of Exchange, but in 2007+ I know it suppresses duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please guide me to any Microsoft documentation that confirms this? I am recommending my BizTalk team plan Active Directory for server login as well as email group settings, and any resource I can quote on this will be very helpful in the planning process. Thanks.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839949

Look at Q7/A7, which talks about how the expected behavior is to detect duplicates.  In my experience this always works, but as you can see Microsoft is acknowledging that this is a feature here.

Comment: Great! I appreciate your help.